# typescript not strict keyof type, I need type that accepts zero or more keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

E.g. I have this object below(Props), so I want to create a type, which is similar to

`PickProps extends Pick<Props, keyof Props>`

I want to use as a type Pick<Props, "key1"> or Pick<Props, "key1 | key2"> and so o. I'm wondering, is there a way to do what I want?

```
    const Props={
     key1:"lel",
     key2:'kek', 
     key3:'test'
    }
```

Here Some more examples of use cases

"" - valid

"key1" - valid

"key1 | key2" valid

"key1 | key2 | key3" valid

"key1 | asfsdgsdgfdsg" - invalid

Comment: @pilchard PickOld extends Pick<OldProps, Partial<keyof OldProps>> I've already tried this, but no luck

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but why don't use just `Partial<Props>`? You want to disallow additional keys?

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve my goal using `PickProps extends Pick<Partial<Props>, keyof Props>`. Wrapping with Partial not the second type "keyof Props" but the Props itself as the first type in Pick